# Hiding WLAN password when pushing to GitHub

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, version-control

I have started to use GitHub to store Arduino code. However some of my code uses the SSID and password for my WLAN which I don’t want published.

A common way of handling this in non-embedded programming is to use a configuration file, but that doesn’t seem to be a viable approach in programming the Arduino. I’m currently just commenting out the sensitive information before pushing it to GitHub, but one day I’m sure I’ll forget.

Is there another – better - way of handling this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can use a config file. It's called a "header" file, and you just `#include` it in your sketch.

```
[config.h (not pushed)]

const char *password = "DOD982yp398fhgpwbn09tupf0p04";

[sketch.ino (pushed)]

#include "config.h"

// Now you can use the password variable.
```

Another method, which is better if you have multiple files in your sketch, is to use `#define` instead of variables in your header file:

```
[config.h]

#define WIFI_PASSWORD "348r0yp80ytwp85tpj8yjp98y97t8t"

[sketch.ino]

#include "config.h"

const char *password = WIFI_PASSWORD;
```

Comment: Of course! It never occurred to me to use a header file in this way. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: One thing to watch is if you have multiple files in your sketch and you include that config file in each you will get errors about multiple definitions. In that case it's probably better to use #define instead of defining the variables directly.  I'll post an example.

Answer (score 7):

You could commit the following file into your project, named
credentials.h:

```
// Replace with your actual SSID and password:

#define WIFI_SSID "Your SSID here"
#define WIFI_PASSWD "WLAN AP password here"
```

Near the beginning of your sketch, you add:

```
#include "credentials.h"

const char ssid[] = WIFI_SSID;
const char password[] = WIFI_PASSWD;
```

Now, you can edit credentials.h to add your real SSID and password, and
go on with your normal git workflow, with one exception: never
`git add credentials.h` again, nor `git commit -a`.

Now, git will always remind you that credentials.h has been modified and
is not staged for commit. It will do so even if you add the file to your
.gitignore. If you always review your changes before committing, this is
only a minor inconvenience. If, on the other hand, you tend to
`git commit -a` without reviewing what you are committing, then this
solution is likely not for you.

---

**Edit**: An idea I got from reading Chris Stratton's comments. **If**
you use a Makefile in your own workflow (this has already been discussed
in this site a few times), you could commit this credentials.h to your
repo:

```
#ifndef CREDENTIALS_H
#define CREDENTIALS_H

// Replace with your actual SSID and password:
#define WIFI_SSID "Your SSID here"
#define WIFI_PASSWD "WLAN AP password here"

#endif
```

Make a copy of this file named true-credentials.h and put the real
credentials there (but do not rename the include guard). Then add to
your Makefile

```
CFLAGS += -include true-credentials.h
```

Keep true-credentials.h and the Makefile out of the repo. You can add
them to your .gitignore or, better yet, to .git/info/exclude.

Now you have a compilable version with dummy credentials in the
repository, you have the true credentials when you compile on your own
machine, and git does not bother you about credentials.h being changed.

Comment: Interesting points and thanks. Looks like I am going to have to be more careful in how I use git.

Comment: This is a better solution, however, no, git *will not* tell you about changes to files in .gitignore unless you explicitly add them.  And adding a file explicitly excluded by .gitignore typically requires adding with a force flag.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In my test, I added and committed the dummy credentials.h, then modified the file and added it to .gitignore. Git kept telling me “Changes not staged for commit: modified: credentials.h”. My point was to have a compilable version on the repo, hence the dummy credentials.h added there.

Comment: If you commit a dummy version, yes.  You may want to give the dummy version a different name, like `credentials.h.CUSTOMIZE_ME` or something, and perhaps back it up with a `#ifndef` `#error` giving instructions to make a copy without the suffix and edit.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, my idea won't work since the `#include` will fail without the custom message.  Really shows the primitiveness of the Arduino IDE compared to something permitting a sensible project file or a custom Makefile.

Comment: Eventually settled on the approach of adding the `credentials.h` reference to the `.git/info/exclude` file and having  a dummy `credentials_CUSTOMIZE_ME.h` file tracked by git (as explained above).  Also, added a `README.md` file to explain everything. Not using a Makefile at the moment, but that may change. Many thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Building upon the shoulders of giants I took Edger Bonet's answer and used a slightly different twist.  I went this route because I don't use a makefile and found this solution works well for me in my project.

I created a placeholder credentials.h file with the following info (Edger's answer).

```
#ifndef CREDENTIALS_H
#define CREDENTIALS_H

// Replace with your actual SSID and password:
#define WIFI_SSID "Your SSID here"
#define WIFI_PASSWD "WLAN AP password here"

#endif
```

I further added the reference to this new file in the .ino file.

```
#include "credentials.h"

const char ssid[] = WIFI_SSID;
const char pass[] = WIFI_PASSWD;
```

Now the twist.. I excluded the file from being checked for changes using the --assume-unchanged command.

> git update-index --assume-unchanged credentials.h

You can then modify the credentials.h file and wont be prompted to add it to github.

Note, to re-check the file use --no-assume-unchanged.

Comment: Kudos for the `--assumed-unchanged` tip!